# Slide transitions blur elements on top of it in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, jquery-cycle2, rotatetransform

Firefox seems to be acting strangely when it comes to `z-index` and `position:absolute` items that are stacked on top of each-other.

I have a menu on top of a slideshow (powered by [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/)), but I decided to complicate things by using `transform: rotate(45deg);` on a container and then `transform: rotate(-45deg);` on the item inside of it to create a diamond-like effect. I created two sets of these, one for the slideshow and one for the menu. Here's an example:

```
<div class="rotate-plus45 slide-holder">
  <div class="rotate-minus45">

   <div class="slideshow">
     <img src="img1.jpg" />
     <img src="img2.jpg" />
   </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="rotate-plus45 menu-holder">
  <div class="rotate-minus45">

   <ul class="menu">
     <li>Item</li>
     <li>Item</li>
     <li>Item</li>
     <li>Item</li>
   </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the problem:** When the slideshow transitions, the text positioned on top of it blurs. **This issue seems exclusive to Firefox on Mac OSX.**

Strangely, creating a jsFiddle does not duplicate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2oywbn4m/1/

However, the issue does exist on my [dev site](http://dev.sunsetgordon.com/).

I've done a lot of tooling around, and removing `transform: rotate(45deg);` from the menu seems to be the only thing that solves the problem... however, I need that effect to achieve my diamond effect (I do not want to resort to using images).

**EDIT**: It appears that the `transform` rotation is definitely part of the problem, but only part. Doing that alone doesn't seem to cause an issue (see my jsFiddle). I'm just not sure what other factor causes this effect. It's not a font issue and it's not a `z-index` issue. It's not a `background:rgba()` issue. It's also not an issue with the plugin itself. Using other transition effects and other slider plugins still cause this problem.

---

[image: Regular State]

Regular State

[image: On Transition (In Firefox 31.0 for OSX)]

On Transition

UPDATE: This appears to be a conflict with ClearType, which Cycle2 has addressed: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/cleartype.html?v3

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    cleartype:  false // disable cleartype corrections 
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about the text in the menu above the slideshow? I'm using Firefox and it looks okay on my end.

Comment: I am using OSX. Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yeah, I'm on Windows.

Comment: It seems like it works properly on every major browser in Windows. I updated my question to reflect this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Something like this fiddle, but with rotation? http://jsfiddle.net/gAv2E/1/

Comment: @IGotRoot: I don't believe so. I added a screen capture to show my issue. This is something happening on multiple machines. It appears that the `transform` rotation is part of the problem, but only part. Doing that alone doesn't seem to cause an issue. I'm just not sure what other factor causes this effect.

Comment: @MisterManSam: Can you send me your recreation? That would help me tremendously.

Comment: Note that removing `overflow: hidden;` "fixes" the bug.

Comment: You are right. Which is even stranger because I have `overflow:hidden;` set in my jsFiddle and there is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug workaround.

- Get the triangle corners needed using a triangle border on pseudo elements.
- <strike>Remove that `overflow: hidden` to prevent the bug.</strike> 
  Remove those now un-needed transforms to prevent the bug, and
  re-position your header.

You will need to play with widths to get the right result, but [here is my basic concept](http://jsbin.com/xegijo/1/edit).

[image: screenshot]

Here is your triangle border for the top:

```
.head-top:before {
content: '';
height: 0px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
border-top: 3em solid transparent;
top: 0px;
width: 0px;
border-left: 3em solid rgba(121, 201, 201, 0.9);
right: -3em;
}
```

Here is your triangle border for the bottom:

```
.head-bottom:before {
content: '';
height: 0px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 0px;
border-left: 80px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-top: 80px solid transparent;
right: -80px;
}
```

Example changes:

(only the width has been changed)

```
.head-top {
position: absolute;
left: 35%;
height: 3em;
top: 6px;
padding: 1em 4em;
width: 50%;
}
```

(only the width has been changed)

```
.head-bottom {
position: absolute;
left: 25%;
height: 80px;
top: 54px;
width: 63.6%;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. I'd like to say that I'll be implementing it, but the client will likely be going a different direction :/